# Datetime format varies in IE10 and chrome browsers

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, web-services, asp.net-web-api

I am using web API controller. If I return date object without formatting,

I am return data collection as following,

```
public IEnumerable<Event> GetData()
{            
    return new NORTHWNDEntities().Events.ToList();
}
```

I get the client side(ajax success) at following format in Chrome:

```
Mon May 05 2014 22:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

and the following in IE:

```
Mon May 5 16:00:00 UTC+0530 2014
```

**I want to get the following format:**

```
Mon May 05 2014 22:30:00
```

Someone please guide me in this regard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could format how your `DateTime` is before it is returned to the client from in your code behind. Use `ToString` method on your `DateTime` object in the code behind with format `"ddd MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss"` like this:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(); //replace this with your actual DateTime instance
string str = dt.ToString("ddd MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

Then pass your `str` as part of the `object` you pass to your client page.

Check this [page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) for more info on `DateTime` format.